# function dynamic list call

Tags: c#, .net

How to make this function dynamic. 
I do not want global variable 
For example:

**I start with: call true**

I need some data and i know `List<string> Files` does not contains. so `List<string> Files` should recive the data form `List<string> RealFile` function

> for foreach (string arg in Files(true)) {}

**Just give me the data: call false** previous and do not refresh the info

> for foreach (string arg in Files(false)) {}

**refresh and return new data: call true** I need new data

> for foreach (string arg in Files(true)) {}

```
public static List<string> Files = RealFile(bool state);
private static List<string> RealFile(Boolean Reload)
{
    if (!Reload)
        return Files(false);
    try
    {
        return Files(true);
    }
    catch (Exception) { return Files(false); }
}
```

Comment: why not `return Files;`?

Comment: I have change all the returns to Files  for the sake of  the question

Comment: Well, it looks confusing. If your original code was something else, use something more like it, that makes sense.

Comment: Whether `true` or `false`, exception comes or not, you are always returning `Files`. So why not `return Files`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[optaional argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)** and set `default value for the parameters` to make them optional. This makes it possible to call ReadFile with or without arguments. `You can call ReadFile(true) or ReadFile();`

```
public static List<string> Files = RealFile(true);
private static List<string> RealFile(Boolean Reload=true)
{
      if (!Reload)
          return Files;
      try
      {
          return Files;
      }
      catch (Exception) { return Files; }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it. how does default value RealFile(true) make the call to Files(false) dynamic?

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: well, the "Reload" in function RealFile  should depend on Files(parameter). for foreach (string arg in Files(false)) immediately return

Comment: @Power-Mosfet: I don't think that is dynamic, which means something else very different. You need to clarify your question to explain what exactly you want.

Comment: I am not clear what you really want to achieve, as there is not foreach loop in your posted question.